# Why does 'delegate' Constructor needs two parameters?

Tags: c#, delegates

Delegate(Object, String)
Delegate(Type, String)

Delegate constructor has two parameters first one holds the reference/Type of objects to which the methods belongs and the second holds the pointer to method.

Why the reference/Type of object is needed when we have address of method directly? what is its use?

Comment: Those are protected constructors. You would never call them directly. Could you give more details about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: The "address" of the method is always the same. So, if you're creating a delegate to an *instance* method, it tells you nothing about *which instance* you're meant to call that method on.

Comment: This is similar to call a method via reflection. You need an *instance* to call an *instance*-member.

Answer (score 2):

I can only speculate about this. As you say the arguments are meant to specify a target (type or instance) and method name. The source code on .NET 4.7.2 is this:

[image]

This constructor really does nothing more than initialize a delegate instance. It is unused:

[image]

Delegates are compiler generated types. I don't know to what extent it is possible to customize delegates using IL. It looks like these constructors were meant either for advanced scenarios that were never necessary, or an outright violation of the responsibility principle. The delegate class has no business in accepting method names and performing reflection over types. There are cleaner existing APIs for creating delegates from reflection. No need to use IL to write a custom derived type.

The .NET Framework has some obsolete stuff from the very early days. All in all it is amazing to me how clean the .NET Framework is. Find a few design bugs here and there is not a sign of a bad code base.

Comment: Concur with you... Probably when they created .NET they weren't sure how they should treat delegates (see for example the fact that all `Delegate` are in truth `MulticastDelegate`)

Comment: @xanatos yes! And to me it is very questionable if delegates should be multicast at all. It seems like a hack to make events work. In my mind an event should be a normal class with a list of "singlecast" delegates. To late to change it now.

Answer (score 0):

> Delegate constructor has two parameters first one holds the reference/Type of objects to which the methods belongs and the second holds the pointer to method.

Take a better look at the signature: the second parameter is a `string`. The basic idea was probably that those two constructors would work in a similar way to `Type.GetMethod(string)`, so find a method inside a type given its name but on top of this the constructor would bind it to the newly created delegate. Note that this constructor is `protected`, so you would need a derived `Delegate` type to call this constructor, and from the derived delegate type the parameter types of the method could be desumed.

So

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(int n);
```

and then the idea was that you could:

```
var obj = new List<int>();

// an instance void Add(int) method is searched in the obj.GetType() type
// and bound to the del delegate
MyDelegate del = new MyDelegate(obj, "Add");
del(1); // obj.Add(1);
```

This feature wasn't implemented. You can use the:

```
MyDelegate del = (MyDelegate)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(MyDelegate), obj, "Add", true);
del(1); // obj.Add(1);
```

but the `CreateDelegate()` doesn't use constructor you asked about.

About delegates and (native) pointers to methods: in truth, when you create a new delegate referencing a method (technically a "method group"), a native pointer to the method is used. It can be seen in this [example on sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgzAAgCYFMIoOYENgoTAFgQBUUBnYAETUxxQAoBKAbgFgAoBLhD+fAJgQBhHuwDeHbvkSEEASQB2FLAoDGKALIpgACwD2SJqKkTO3AL6TuVrnxgBGAGz4iAZWA4wqrboNGbCKZSlmZcAXykFNTo2LgIAEIArpBIispqmtr6SNG0uEwBQVLckVQ0sXi4FAgAvPJKHhk+2WyhxTAA7AhVwK3BHOGIpbkVCckQSO6e3lkGI3QFbUXFJORlMXTda7UIU8BezQZ9K/hdPcdcIeZAA==):

```
public delegate void TestDelegate();

public TestDelegate BuildInstanceMethodDelegate()
{
    TestDelegate test = InstanceMethod;
    return test;
}

public TestDelegate BuildStaticMethodDelegate()
{
    TestDelegate test = StaticMethod;
    return test;
}
```

is translated in IL code to:

```
.class public auto ansi sealed TestDelegate
    extends [mscorlib]System.MulticastDelegate
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor (
            object 'object',
            native int 'method'
        ) runtime managed 
    {
    } // end of method TestDelegate::.ctor
}
```

and

```
.method public hidebysig 
    instance class TestDelegate BuildInstanceMethodDelegate () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2052
    // Code size 13 (0xd)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldftn instance void C::InstanceMethod()
    IL_0007: newobj instance void TestDelegate::.ctor(object, native int)

.method public hidebysig 
    instance class TestDelegate BuildStaticMethodDelegate () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2060
    // Code size 13 (0xd)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldnull
    IL_0001: ldftn void C::StaticMethod()
    IL_0007: newobj instance void TestDelegate::.ctor(object, native int)
```

The calls to the `TestDelegate::.ctor(object, native int)` are quite clear, and we can see the [`ldftn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldftn(v=vs.110).aspx) IL instruction that *Pushes an unmanaged pointer (type native int) to the native code implementing a specific method onto the evaluation stack.* . We can even look the instruction before the `ldftn`: it can be a reference if the delegate is to an instance method, or `ldnull` if it is to a static method.